# Google home action: refresh google home page after state changes, change set point temp range for thermostat

Tags: actions-on-google

I have a cloud solution and a thermostat which works with it. I've integrated Google Home Action for thermostat: Sync, Query, Execute calls - it works.

I have next issues:

***First***

---

1) I add thermostat to Google Home Android App (Successfull)

2) Open that thermostat via Google Home App

3) Change thermostat temperature manually (not via Google Home App)

**Expected result:** Google Home App will refresh UI automaticaly and show correct temperatue

**Actual Result:** Nothing changes till I manualy refresh App.

**What I've tried to do** - Successfully implemented Report State

***Second***

---

1) I add thermostat to Google Home Android App (Successfull)

2) Open that thermostat via Google Home App

**Expected result:** Should be able to change set point temperature in range of my custom values (For example from 5°C to 40°C )

**Actual Result:** The range limit for set point temperature is from 10°C to 32°C and I'm not able to change it.

**What I've tried to do** - Added **thermostatTemperatureSetpointHigh** and **thermostatTemperatureSetpointLow** states to sync command. here is an example of sync response:

```
    {
  "payload": {
    "agentUserId": "123456",
    "devices": [
      {
        "id": "321654",
        "type": "action.devices.types.THERMOSTAT",
        "traits": [
          "action.devices.traits.TemperatureSetting"
        ],
        "name": {
          "defaultNames": [
            "Bathroom"
          ],
          "name": "Bathroom",
          "nicknames": [
            "Bathroom"
          ]
        },
        "willReportState": false,
        "roomHint": null,
        "deviceInfo": {
          "manufacturer": "MyManufacturer",
          "model": "",
          "hwVersion": "113",
          "swVersion": "113"
        },
        "customData": null,
        "attributes": {
          "thermostatTemperatureSetpointLow": 5,
          "thermostatTemperatureSetpointHigh": 40,
          "availableThermostatModes": "heat,cool",
          "thermostatTemperatureUnit": "C"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "requestId": "197361223046164267"
}
```

I've checked the API documentations and searched a lot - no results. 
Please help to solve it.

Comment: Is this only affecting the visual UI? Can you still use voice to set the temperatures?

Comment: Yes, It looks like just a UI limitation

Comment: I've filed a bug for the UI issue.

Comment: @NickFelker which issue did you report? First or second?

Comment: @NickFelker I have also Xiaomi Smart lights and I've tride to reproduce the first issue - it was repoducible. I added Xiaomi smart light to Google Home App -> Opened device in Google Home App -> Changed device brigness manualy (not by Google Home App) -> UI in Google Home App didn't change, it still showed the previous brighness value.

Comment: Both issues are being tracked

Comment: Thanks. Is this an internal issue tracking system or you can share a link for it?

Comment: It's internal only.